# Byte Buddy - HotSwap with ByteBuddyAgent

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm trying to use the HotSwap feature of byte buddy. Unfortunately I receive some errors. I have read the documentation on the [official website](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial), and I'm aware that it only works when the program use a Java agent. I have tried to put -javaagent parameter  on the startup of the Java virtual machine which looks like this:

> -javaagent:C:\lib\byte-buddy-agent-0.5.6.jar

This produces the following error when starting my application:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.Installer

FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)   at
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)   at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)   at
    sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:304)
    at
    sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
    Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Nevertheless I tried use the `ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK()` method instead of the -javaagent parameter in hope that will solve the problem. But this throws following error, which relies on the same problem I think:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$Installer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:304)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:411)
Apr 09, 2015 1:35:01 PM net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent doInstall
INFORMATION: Cannot delete temporary file: C:\Users\Flo\AppData\Local\Temp\byteBuddyAgent4745240427430305215.jar
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The programmatic installation of the Byte Buddy agent is only possible on the OpenJDK and JDKs with a compatible 'tools.jar'
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK(ByteBuddyAgent.java:176)
    at hotswapping.FXMLDocumentController.handleByteBuddyButton(FXMLDocumentController.java:90)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.doInstall(ByteBuddyAgent.java:199)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK(ByteBuddyAgent.java:174)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:121)
    ... 67 more
```

Does anyone know what is the problem or have I misunderstood something from the tutorial? Btw I tried it with jdk1.7.0_55 and jdk1.8.0_40 and use neatbeans as ide. Version of byte buddy which I am using is v0.5.6.
Thanks for helping.

**EDIT:**

It seems that the error with the -javaagent parameter is a bug in the current version, thanks [Rafael Winterhalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237575/rafael-winterhalter) for the quick response.

I also figured out what was problem with the `ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK()` method. It was a really stupid mistake from my side. It seems my netbeans use an older java version as jdk1.8.0_40, so I changed the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable in the `netbeans.conf` file in the etc folder of netbeans. Now that my netbeans use the same java version as my projects it seems that it works like a charm even with JavaFX applications. The only strange thing is that this error occurred only in JavaFX applications, in normal Java applications I never had this problems. FYI: Here is the code sample of my JavaFX application:

```
package testbytebuddy;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;

public class TestByteBuddy extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start application");
        ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK();
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("End application");

    }

}
```

Comment: The first one fails due to a bug, the last dot should be a dollar sign. Sorry for that, it will be fixed for the next release. Did you try to run the install on open jdk method by itself in a main method on your VM? I wonder if there is a class loader confusion. Also, do you run a Mac? Their jvms differ sometimes and I only test on Linux and Windows.

Comment: First of all thank you for your the quick response. I use a windows 8.1 machine. What exactly do you mean by "the last dot should be a dollar sign"?

Yes I run the install on open jdk method in the main method. It's a javaFx application an it always fails at this point. For testing purpose I tried the install on open jdk method on a normal java application. It seems it works there because I dont get any error. Maybe it relies on the javaFX application?

Comment: About $, I mean that I accidentally reference the Installer class as being in a package named ByteBuddyAgent, not as being an inner class. Have you tried installing the agent outside of JavaFX? You can later fetch it by calling the getInstrumentation method. Anyways, I want to look into it l. Could you build a minimal code example that reproduces the error? Would help a ton!

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand. I just figured out what was the problem with the install on open jdk method (See edit of my post). The only strange thing is that only JavaFX applications were affected. Nervermind, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using the agent directly is a bug in Byte Buddy where I reference the agent's main class with `net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.Installer` and not with `net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$Installer` as it would be correct. This will be fixed for Byte Buddy 0.5.7 which should be released at the end of April / beginning of Mai.

For the second error, it seems like you used a bundled JDK that does not allow the programmatic attachment of the agent. It was difficult to see as this resultet in a similar error message. The programmatic attachment is however something that can go wrong, therefore it is difficult to provide more detailed information on the actual cause. Good you figured it out.

*This answer was already solved in the comments, this should serve as an overview for potential future readers.*